# Is there a way to use setValue:forKey which will take C-type variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some properties set up on an object, mostly `GLfloat` and I was wondering if there was a way to use `[self setValue:(id)value forKey:(id)key];` that would take a c style variable?

It doesn't have to be `setValue:forKey` if there is an alternative if there is one available.

My reasoning is I have a lot of properties on an object that are `floats` and I can pass an `NSDictionary` with values (`NSNumber` here is no issue) to set each relevant value.

Ideally I could do this without enumerators or custom setters - is this doable?

Comment: You can always use NSValue objects to "wrap" other entities.  Not necessarily convenient.  But, of course, NSNumber works for floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Similarly, `setValue:forKey:` determines the data type required by the
>   appropriate accessor or instance variable for the specified key. If
>   the data type is not an object, then the value is extracted from the
>   passed object using the appropriate -Value method.

You can pass an `NSNumber`, and it will be automatically converted back into a float for your setter.

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat example;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)testSetter {
    [self setValue:@(5.0f) forKey:@"example"];
}

@end
```

Comment: How is your answer different to the other answer?

Comment: The other answer didn't explain weather the property is still a float, or weather the property is a NSNumber. (The automatic value conversion)

Answer (score 4):

You can automatically box any value into a NSNumber using the new Objective-C syntax:

```
GLfloat alpha;
alpha = 2.3f;

[self setValue:@(alpha) forKey:@"theKey"];
```

This will automatically convert the float into an NSNumber for you with minimal fuss.

Comment: i just tried this and going @alpha gives an error 'unexpected '@' in program'