# Xcode IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch loads CPU infinitely?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have a .xib file with extensive usage of `IBDesignable` views. As view grown I noticed constant CPU load. Now, my view is really big and when I open it in interface builder, ActivityMonitor show this:
[image]. It continues even if I leave .xib file and go to code. The only solution to stop it is to close, then open Xcode and don't open .xib file until it is really necessary. My rough assumption is that Xcode continues compiling my project/views in background to maintain `IBDesignable` views in actual state.

What should I do to prevent wasting CPU?

If it could make any sense - my mac configuration:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug report with Apple. https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Got any news? Got the same problem, and the Macbook Air can' really handle all this load!

Comment: Same here. It's been a problem for a while, but seems to be getting worse.

Answer (score 3):

I've got pretty much same issue and solved it by removing all `IBDesignable` from project, but then I realized that you can just disable `Automatically Refresh Views` in `Editor` menu as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138935/584500).

Issue returned later on just to *some* XIBs. The reason was `Top Bar` in `Simulated Metrics` on this view, which is really unexpected. Removing all simulated metrics solves CPU loading issue for me.