# ios - Xcode 9.4.1 stuck loading in main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, xcode9.4

I am using `Xcode 9.4.1`. Xcode working perfectly in all project but **one of my latest project**. When i am trying add **any type of `UIView`** in `Main.Storyboard` then Xcode stared hangup and after forced quit xcode hangup in project loading. And also i monitor in Activity monitor `IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch` and `Interface Builder Cocoa Touch` using 99% CPU.

Anyone know why this happen?

Comment: don't get it. can you explain in details? @vivekDas

Comment: but the problem in storyboard

Comment: @vivekDas how does that have anything to do with adding views in Interface Builder?

Comment: @SakirSherasiya do you have any custom `IBDesignable` views in your project?

Comment: @mag_zbc yes i have

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546591/xcode-ibdesignablesagentcocoatouch-loads-cpu-infinitely) seem to refer to the same/similar issue. You can try removing `@IBDesignable` across your project

Answer (score 0):

Try separating into multiple storyboards and then connect the view controllers with storyboard references. It was happening to me as well after I did that my issue was resolved, probably because I had a lot of view controllers in just one storyboard.

Comment: I also had to change some of my code but I had no other choice because there was a point when I even touched the view controller it crashed.