# Xcode constantly building an compiling project

Tags: ios, xcode8

Xcode 8 constantly rebuilds my entire project for every line change, it is very frustrating and slows down the machine tremendously.
Why does this happen, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Do you have an `IBDesignable` view anywhere? If I remember correctly, they can cause constant reloading of the interface builder.

Comment: @ezcoding Yes, one view.  Surely Xcode cant be THAT buggy?

Comment: Well, it has to reload the interface builder to display the changes. Anyway, remove the `@IBDesignable` and associated keywords and look if the constant recompiling goes away.

Comment: @ezcoding But the IBDesignable is not at all related to the viewController I am working on

Comment: using storyboards?

Comment: @ezcoding Yes I am

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago and this is how I fixed it. Now I can't say for sure that you are experiencing the same thing I did, that's why I'm commenting and not handing it in as proposed answer ;)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476030/xcode-keeps-building-storyboard-after-each-keystroke

Answer (score 1):

Try removing IBDesignable if you use any in your classes. I had the same problem with Xcode 9 and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`. Select Build in left side column and uncheck "**Find implicit dependencies**"

But this flag should remain checked when you are building the project for first time.

Read about Find implicit dependencies in detail [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/managing_xcode.html#scheme-action).