# Xcode 8 freezes on Signing product

Tags: xcode, xcode8, code-signing

I can no longer access any `storyboards or XIBs` in my project. As soon as I do,`Xcode` starts building and when it gets to Signing product it just hangs. I left it open for about half an hour, nothing happens. I need to Force Quit every time.

Signing works otherwise thou, that's the weird part. I can build normally, I can run on simulator, device, I can archive, everything is fine, EXCEPT when I open an IB file.

I tried all the usual, deleting `DerivedData`, `cleaning everything`, nothing seems to work. This is extremely frustrating and I can't find anything on the subject.

I'm using `Xcode 8.2 beta (8C30a)` currently, but it's also happening in the release `8.1`.

Comment: I was having the same problem. Did you have any response from the bug report? I found this [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476030/xcode-keeps-building-storyboard-after-each-keystroke)

Comment: Hi dear, did you get any solution? I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you file a bug report with a bit more info? Please provide a copy of the build log and the output of `sysdiagnose Xcode` (it will produce an archive).

http://bugreporter.apple.com/

Thanks!

Comment: I did, 4 days later, nothing.

Comment: @Horea Do you have a radar number that I can reference? Thanks!