# Xcode bug 8.2.1 : unknown behaviour of Xcode, shows building after some time of start

Tags: xcode

I was working on my project but don't know what happened. It just started showing building process over and over again without any press of button. See image for reference:

[image]

The problem with it is that my code goes grey and no suggestions come up!

I tried closing it and opening again and restarted my system but none of those worked.

it starts doing it after i first build it, then it goes on and on
it shows the following processes : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UfOy.png)

EDIT:

I also re-installed it, didn't worked even after new installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode keeps building storyboard after each keystroke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476030/xcode-keeps-building-storyboard-after-each-keystroke)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would try:

1. Clean your project: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
2. Clean your build folder: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
3. Delete the derived data*:

   ```
   sudo rm -R ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   ```
4. Delete Xcode caches*:

   ```
   sudo rm -R ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
   ```

Restart Xcode and build you project.

*<sub>Run this in Terminal</sub>

Comment: @GurjotKalsi Did you try the suggestions in the [link posted below your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476030/xcode-keeps-building-storyboard-after-each-keystroke)? The answer to that question linked to might solve your problem.

Comment: yes i did, the trick to stop reloading the view from IB is good, but not effective. My xcode give stupid suggestions, when i start writing a string it suggests when i write  a function or method or any other thing it dont , just give me image names.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a wild guess, but Xcode will try to build your product (or parts of it) if you have classes that are tagged desingable (`IB_DESIGNABLE` in Obj-C, `@IBDesignable` in Swift). These classes can be drawn in Interface Builder, just like UI classes from Apple (e.g. just like `UIButton` is drawn there for real) but therefor Xcode needs to build them first, together with all their dependencies (every other UI or data class they might be using). And any time you alter the class or any of its dependent classes, Xcode will try to rebuild it.