# Xcode 9 builds all targets after any code

Tags: xcode9

Xcode 9 builds on any code change or any keystroke. I'm using Version 9.1 (9B55)

Comment: Are you using storyboards with IBDesignables?

Comment: That was it. Excellent, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476030/xcode-keeps-building-storyboard-after-each-keystroke

Answer (score 3):

This sometimes happens if you are using storyboards with @IBDesignables. To fix the issue, select a storyboard and uncheck Editor > Automatically Refresh Views.

This happens because IBDesignable's re-compile your code so that they can properly render their views in the storyboard.